# Selecting two referencing column and show them in one column, while adding string to it

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have one table called MsUser

```
UserID || Name
 1     || Danny
 2     || William
 3     || Rinoa
```

and another (difficult) table

```
UserID A || UserID B
  1      ||      2
  2      ||      1
  3      ||      1
```

How do I write query to select them like this one below?

```
    GameReport
Danny kills William
William kills Danny
Rinoa kills Danny
```

Is it even possible to do? :/ (By the way, I use SQL server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is concatenate so the print output looks the way you want, you could do it this way:

```
SELECT mu.Name + ' kills ' + mu2.Name
FROM msUser mu
INNER JOIN difficultTable dt ON dt.UserIDA = mu.UserID
INNER JOIN msUser mu2 ON mu2.UserID = dt.UserIDB
```

This will essentially join MsUser to your Difficult table on the IDA, and rejoin the MsUser table to your Difficult table on IDB

Comment: oh my, I guess I'm not that used with the concept yet :/ Big thanks, dude.